# android disappearing poof animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am creating a preschool age game and want to add a poof animation with settling dust when an image view is clicked. Think of a magician's act then they disappear on stage. After the animation is played, the image will no longer be visiable.

I have no idea how to accomplish this and need some direction. Is this even possible with android animations? Do I need to create a gif that does this instead and show that on click?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various answers can be found here:
http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/1yqebf/android_advanced_animations/

Create a sequence of images using photoshop or some flash tool. Use [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) to display them in the order needed.

A tutorial can be [found here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_imageswitcher.htm).

Comment: Thanks for this extra post!